# Slider Revolution Dynamic Link

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, slider-revolution

In wordpress, I have posts that offer the user the ability to choose a custom link (using ACF) with the intention that it would be used in revolution slider to dynamically link to somewhere other than the permalink. This works without issue using a simple link action and {{meta:customlink}} as the link. However what I'm trying to solve is, if a user doesn't want to use a custom link and would prefer to use the permalink for a specific post is there a way to tell slider revolution, "if {{meta:customlink}} is empty, use {{link}} instead.

I tried adding two actions, both simple links, in the hopes that when {{meta:customlink}} is empty it would simply not have data to pull in and would then default to the second action. However, that didn't solve the issue, as the first action with the empty custom link defaulted to the current pages url.

Additionally, if possible, I would prefer that {{meta:customlink}} opens in a new tab/window and {{link}} opens in the same window.